# What should go in the Procfile for a Rails app?

Tags: heroku

I'm in the process of deploying my Rails app (it also uses redux, react, as well as some Ruby and Javascript). And I'm on the step in the official Heroku guide where it specifies to add a `Procfile`.

I assume that these are the commands that will run once the apps starts up; what exactly do I need to put in here for a Rails app that uses a database?

Locally, I know that to start my app I run `rails s`, as well as setting up the database beforehand; do I need to do something like that in the `Procfile`?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#create-a-procfile